# Are "private" folders possible with folder redirection and offline files synchronization?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, windows-vista, folder-redirection

I'm considering using offline folder synchronization with folder redirection using Server 2008 + Windows XP & Vista clients.

Currently I'm not using redirection at all.  Every user has a personal folder on the file share that is readable by everyone and writable by the user.  Inside this folder is a private folder to which only the user can read & write files.  Thus most of a user's files can be accessed by others if they are away from the office, except those that need to be kept in confidence.

If I use folder redirection with offline file sync, is it possible to keep these private folders?  If so, will they be available offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you redirecting? My Documents, App Data? AFAIK, you can't redirect custom folders via GPO, meaning you can't redirect folders that aren't in the pre-built list of folders available for redirection. What do you mean "keep these folders"? Do you mean "will they be redirected?"

***EDIT***

The answers should be: yes & yes. What I would recommend is to configure this for a single user as a test by moving the user to a sub OU of their current OU and linking a new GPO that has your redirection settings to this sub OU.

Comment: Sorry.  If I redirect My Documents, and the share it redirects to contains folders, will those folders be synchronized as part of My Documents?  If so, it is possible for those folders to have different permissions?

Comment: The answers should be: yes & yes. What I would recommend is to configure this for a single user as a test by moving the user to a sub OU of their current OU and linking a new GPO that has your redirection settings to this sub OU.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If you can edit your answer to include what you've said in your comment I'll hit the accept button.